# sas macro variable in loop thru end of month

Tags: loops, variables, sas, sas-macro

my idea is to get a data set from tables where the variable is dynamically created based on the end of the month date. I know I'm missing sth with format/informat of a variable, but I'm super lost, please help me understood what I'm missing:
I need variable YYYYMMDD to look like ie20200229 to be sure to get leap year right.
I have database with no partion that's why each end of month is in different table.

```
%MACRO MEH;
%DO n=2018 %TO 2022;
    &LET yyyy = n;
        %DO i=1 %TO 12;
            %LET mm= i;
            %LET YYYYMMDD= %sysfunc(putn(intnx(month,mdy(( input(&mm.),28,input(&yyyy.)),0,e), YYMMDDN8.));     /*IE. 20200229 */       
RUN;
   /*this part works*/
        PROC SORT DATA=XYZ.NAME_OF_TABLE_&YYYYMMDD.
        out=work.NEW_NAME&YYYYMMDD. nodupkey;
        by SOME_ID;
        RUN;
        /* MORE CODE HERE*/
        DATA work.TEMP2;
        MERGE   work.TEMP1
        work.NEW_NAME&YYYYMMDD;
        BY SOME_ID;
        RUN;
        DATA work.WIN&YYYYMMDD.;
        MERGE   work.TEMP6
                work.TEMP2;
        BY SOME_ID;
        RUN;
        /* MORE CODE Here this code do sorting merging and filtering specific vales i did on SQL but I'm missing some function (like lag, to do in on SQL only) */
    /*END OF WORKING CODE*/

    /*CEAN UP*/
     proc datasets nolist lib=work;
     DELETE NEW_NAME: ;
     DELETE TEMP: ;
     RUN;
%END;
%END;
%MEND MEH;
  %MEH;
```

Comment: I don't see any variables being dynamically created.  It looks like you are trying to dynamically create the name of the dataset instead.  Show the SAS code you want the macro to create for one date (month?).  Explain how the code needs to change to process the next date.

Comment: Variable YYYYMMDD should be changing with each n and i. I did sth similar but with vba and here a get erors on wrong type of variable (macro are charr) or wrong order of functions.

Comment: Why do you have multiple dataset?  Why not just combine the data first.  Then you  can just use normal SAS code and forget about trying to use the macro processor to generate SAS code.

Answer (score 0):

To loop over date intervals it is usually easier to use an integer index.  You can then use INTNX() function to to calculate the next interval's start date.  You can use INTCK() to calculate how many iterations are required.

```
%let start='01JAN2018'd;
%let end='01DEC2012'd;
%do offset=0 %to %sysfunc(intck(month,&start,&end));
  %let ymd = %sysfunc(intnx(month,&start,&offset),yymmddn8.);
  ....
%end;
```

Comment: Thanks I will try it bit later today, I'm super new to sas (I work with it since June :p) it looks like it  might work. Can I use %do outside macro? Like in data step?

Comment: No.  You can only use the %IF/%THEN?%DO/%END macro conditional logic outside of a macro.  Inside a data step you can use a normal DO statement.

Answer (score 0):

- Drop the YYYY and mm macro variables as they're redundant
- Remove the RUN as well, not required

Then you can replace the top of your macro with the following:

```
%DO n=2018 %TO 2022;
     %DO i=1 %TO 12;
          %LET YYYYMMDD= %sysfunc(intnx(month, %sysfunc(inputn(&n.&i., yymmn6.)), 0, e), yymmddn8.);     /*IE. 20200229 */       
          %put &yyyymmdd.; * for testing;
```